# Google Web Fonts not working on Tumblr page in iOS7

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, tumblr

I'm trying to add custom Google Web Fonts to a Tumblr page, but they are not taking effect on mobile (iOS 7). Strangely enough, they work on my laptop just fine. I've added this line at the end of the head tag:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:700|Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and I have

```
font-family: "Dosis", "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Arial, sans-serif;
```

within the h1 selector in the CSS.

Again, the fonts render perfectly fine in Chrome on my laptop, yet they fallback to other (uglier) fonts in mobile Chrome/Safari on iOS7. The fonts render correctly on my Nexus 7, for what it's worth.

In addition, an "Archive" link appears in the iOS7 version, which is not specified anywhere in the HTML, and not present on non-mobile browsers. It appears that Tumblr is changing the HTML specifically for the iPhone; is there a way to disable this, or work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! There's a setting under Advanced Options called "use optimized mobile layout" which, when deselected, fixed my font issue and the unwanted "Archive" link. I had been hesitant to toggle this in fear that it would break the mobile layout, but it still resized to fit the screen.